# boto3 changing AWS ec2 instance state

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

According to the Boto3 [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=vpc#EC2.Vpc.start) and this [diagram](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html)

There are 6 states for an EC2 instance:

`'pending'|'running'|'shutting-down'|'terminated'|'stopping'|'stopped'`

I was wondering how can programmatically set the state to one of these states.

I have some code to view all the states of every instance in my ec2 instance.

```
ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2", region_name="us-west-2")
vpc = ec2.Vpc("vpc-123456")
for instance in vpc.instances.all():
    for tag in instance.tags:
        print(instance.state["Name"])
```

I get the output of

```
running
running
running
running
...
...
```

I was wondering if I can change these states to something like `pending` or `shutting-down`.

Something along the lines of `instance.set("stopping")`. I understand that perhaps if I set a instance to the state of `stopping` I will get `stopped` state the next time I check on this instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't change EC2 instance state values directly. The state changes based on the actions you take to launch/start/stop/terminate instances. Look at the following [Boto3 EC2 client](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#client) methods:

```
run_instances()
start_instances()
stop_instances()
terminate_instances()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Instance.stop()`, `Instance.reboot()`, `Insance.terminate()` resource methods.